# Extending Laravel 4 Eloquent models from within packages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

first of all I'm new to IoC, ServiceProviders and Facades, but I'm guessing the answer lies in those for the following:

What would be the best way to extend Eloquent models from within packages (there are probably more than just one right way, but please do share yours). Here's the application structure I'm planning to have:

L4 framework + two separate packages (CMS & CRM), that will need to share some Eloquent models. However, there might be package specific cases where the package needs to extend the Eloquent model that's being used by both and I wouldn't like to touch the base model.

I'm also planning on using separate controllers and views for each package (unless there's something that will certainly be the same across packages). Master view will be loaded from the L4-views folder. Does this sound right? (At least I played with separate controllers and views already and they worked out fine.)

The reason I want to go with the package approach is that I want the CMS & CRM to be independent code and structure-wise so they can easily be installed & uninstalled & updated via composer.

I'd be more than delighted with any suggestions on achieving all this. Also, if this doesn't seem to make any sense at all, let me know and I'll try to clarify myself :)

Cheers!

Comment: Are you building the CMS & CRM as two standalone apps? You could make your own little class that extends Eloquent, and post it to packagist, then add it to your composer.json

Comment: Yes, and no :) The idea is that they can work alone and together, but within the same Laravel installation. I'm currently studying more about IoC's and Facades to achieve the best results. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you creating a package within Laravel 4 then you should be able to do something like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YourModel extends Model {

    // Your code here
}
```

Note: I was a little unsure on whether you wanted to extend Eloquent or a model you created yourself that extends eloquent?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've realised that my question is quite broad to be answered thoroughly and would rather need a complete tutorial on the topic. At the moment I'm in a point where I have separate packages and models that extend the core, just the way I want them to. I'll accept your answer as it solves my initial question :) Another key to achieving package usage was namespacing which I hadn't used before.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment above, I would consider namepacing to be the correct answer since your models will be sharing functionality and it makes more sense to have them in the same installation rather than separate packages. Here's an example:

in /app/models/Entities/CRM/UserEntity.php

```
<?php namespace Project\Models\Entities\CRM;

use Eloquent;

Class User extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Project\Models\Entities\CMS\User');
    }
}
```

in /app/models/Entities/CMS/UserEntity.php

```
<?php namespace Project\Models\Entities\CMS;

use Eloquent;

Class User extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Project\Models\Entities\CRM\User');
    }
}
```

Not to mention that you should populate the Models namespace in your **composer.json**

```
{
   ...
    "autoload":{
        "psr-0": { "Project\\Models": "app/models/" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mulkave, that's very close to what I did to achieve what I wanted. Thanks for your reply!